# MVC3 ASPX view object does not contain definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I started this project using MVC2, but changed to the MVC3 dll.

I have an Asset entity. In the controller I have the Details ActionResult defined like this:
***EDIT: (Put the correct controller code.)***

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new AssetsContainer())
        {
            return View(db.Assets.Find(id));
        }
    }
```

My Details.aspx page is defined this way:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CITracker.Models.Asset>" %>  
<%@ Import Namespace="CITracker.Models" %>  
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">  
Details  
</asp:Content>  

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Id</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.Id %></div>
```

I get this error:

```
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any ideas why this was working with MVC2 but fails with MVC3? I don't get develop time errors, but I do get runtime errors.

Comment: It looks like you send `IEnumerable<Asset>` and expecting in the view to get `Assest`

Comment: Check your spelling and make sure that your model actually contains an Id property.

Comment: Yes, the Asset entity contains Id.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but looks like this is the problem. You are passing a List to the view

```
return View(db.Assets.ToList());
```

but your Inherits says
`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CITracker.Models.Asset>"` instead of

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<CITracker.Models.Asset>>"
```

And also since your model is now a IEnumerable, you can not do a simple Model.Id instead it should be Model[0].Id (or what ever ith elemnt you choose or you do a foreach)

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong code. As you can see now, I am returning the result from Find(id) for the details.

Comment: Could you put a break point and see what actually is the model object on the view ??

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same problem converting some MVC 2 code to MVC 3.  A simple configuration problem to look for is making sure you have this app setting in your config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

See this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1660481.aspx) for more info.